# Ajax Post request doesn't work on Deployment Asp.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-platform, http-post

I have created application in ASP.Net MVC where I send a login POST request to a `HttpPost` action. This works great on localhost but when deployed to Google Cloud Platform it doesn't hit the action and returns a 404 error.

The action is written in my base controller and here is the code for AJAX request:

```
 $('#btn').click(function(event) {  
            event.preventDefault();  
    var url = '@Url.Action("PostLogin")';
    var name = $("#Name").val();
    var email = $("#Email").val();
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: 'Post',
            data: { 'name': name, 'email': email },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.msg);
            }

        });
        });
```

Here is the code for Post Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostLogin(string name, string email)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

            return Json(new
            {
                msg = "failed to login "
            });
    }
```

I found that changing build mode from `debug` to `release` will work but that didn't. Other POST actions work well without using AJAX.

**Note:** I have HttpGet and HttpPost Actions different names, can I do this (Login and PostLogin).

Comment: In C# `'` is for delimiting chars, not strings. Is that your actual code, as I'm surprised it would work at all on your local server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, that's better syntactically, but was it an issue in your actual code?

Comment: no there wasn't any issue in the code if there was then that shouldn't work on local

Comment: Can you check in DevTools/Network what is the URL that your code call?

Comment: /User/PostLogin

Comment: please post the controller action as well, the model that the controller action is expecting and and a json/xml/whatever example of the data trying to be posted

Comment: by "please post the controller action, etc...." i meant update your question with what I stated, not make a http post TO the controller action

Comment: @GregH I can't post code for login action, although I can just show the empty action

Comment: well it'll be EXTREMELY unlikely for anyone to be able to help you with what you've provided

Comment: is it a typo or your ajax Url should be url? I'm clueless myself if it is case sensitive or not.

Comment: @HastaTamang it is typo